# How to calculate Simple Moving Average in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm just lost and can't seem to know what to do to calculate the simple moving average?

This is one of the method in the file which is used to calculate the simple moving average.

```
        public async Task<decimal?> UpdateAsync(decimal? value, CancellationToken cancelToken)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var av = default(decimal?);

                if (_av.Count - 1 >= _p)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    av = value;
                }

                _av.Add(av);

                return av;
            }, cancelToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

            throw new Exception("major issue");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. You cannot deface your post as you did. Once you post here, the question becomes the property of this site under the Terms of Service you agreed to when posting.

Comment: @KenWhite I understand that sir, but I have already flagged it in terms of this question being not relevant and thought about just deleting the question, though I don't see a reason why you would want to spend your time looking at my question, but if that's what you want than you go ahead and be you.

Comment: Mod Warning: Please do not vandalise your post. This may result in a [question ban](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Comment: You were warned about vandalizing your question several times already, but you didn't listen. I have now locked the question to prevent any further edits.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the question:

> I'm just lost and can't seem to know what to do to calculate the
> simple moving average?

**Given**

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static IEnumerable<decimal> MovingAvg(this IEnumerable<decimal> source, int period)
   {
      var buffer = new Queue<decimal>();

      foreach (var value in source)
      {
         buffer.Enqueue(value);

         // sume the buffer for the average at any given time
         yield return buffer.Sum() / buffer.Count;

         // Dequeue when needed 
         if (buffer.Count == period)
            buffer.Dequeue();
      }
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
static  void Main(string[] args)
{
   var input = new decimal[] { 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
   var result = input.MovingAvg(2);
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",result));
}
```

**Output**

```
1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4.5, 5.5, 6, 6, 7.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all what is moving average

> A simple moving average is a method for computing an average of a stream of numbers by only averaging the last   P   numbers from the stream,   where   P   is known as the period.

Next is the code as how I imagined my moving average to be implemented. It is possible to use `LINQ` but at each and every step after we add a number I want my Average to be updated.

My code is heavily commented so please read the comments.

```
public class MovingAverageCalculator {

    /// <summary>
    /// Maximum number of numbers this moving average calculator can hold.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly int maxElementCount;

    /// <summary>
    /// Numbers which will be used for calculating moving average.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly int[] currentElements;

    /// <summary>
    /// At which index the next number will be added.
    /// </summary>
    private int currentIndex;

    /// <summary>
    /// How many elements are there currently in this moving average calculator.
    /// </summary>
    private int currentElementCount;

    /// <summary>
    /// Current total of all the numbers that are being managed by this moving average calculator
    /// </summary>
    private double currentTotal;

    /// <summary>
    /// Current Average of all the numbers.
    /// </summary>
    private double currentAvg;

    /// <summary>
    /// An object which can calcauclate moving average of given numbers.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="period">Maximum number elements</param>
    public MovingAverageCalculator(int period) {
        maxElementCount = period;
        currentElements = new int[maxElementCount];
        currentIndex = 0;
        currentTotal = 0;
        currentAvg = 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an item to the moving average series then updates the average.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="number">Number to add.</param>
    public void AddElement(int number){
        // You can only have at most maximum elements in your moving average series.
        currentElementCount = Math.Min(++currentElementCount, maxElementCount);
        // IF your current index reached the maximum allowable number then you must reset
        if (currentIndex == maxElementCount){
            currentIndex = 0;
        }
        // Copy the current index number to the local variable
        var temp = currentElements[currentIndex];
        // Substract the value from the current total because it will be replaced by the added number.
        currentTotal -= temp;
        // Add the number to the current index
        currentElements[currentIndex] = number;
        // Increase the total by the added number.
        currentTotal += number;
        // Increase index
        currentIndex++;
        // Calculate average
        currentAvg = (double)currentTotal / currentElementCount;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current average
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Average</returns>
    public double GetAverage() => currentAvg;
}
```

And lastly, I checked your code but It does not make sense to me